# URL's with extra slashes in route do not work with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using code similar to below for routing my application to different route. These routes work as expected when there is no extra slashes in the route but they tend to break if there is an extra slash.

For exmaple: www.example.com// or www.example.com/action//Group1.
These urls do not open any route and a blank screen appear.
Is there a way to make these url's with extra slashes work.

```
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';
import {
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

<ConnectedRouter history={app.history}>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path={action/:selectedGroup?`}
              render={(props) =>
                (<ActionPage {...props} />)
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path={detail/:selectedGroup?`}
              render={(props) =>
                (<DetailsPage {...props} />)
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path={dependency/:selectedGroup?`}
              render={(props) =>
                (<DependencyPage {...props} />)
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/:selectedGroup?"
              render={(props) =>
                (<HomePage {...props} />)
              }
            />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this source [on trailing slashes in react](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4841)?